# Html post form acting as get form

Tags: html, forms, post, get

I am using [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), and `<form action="" method="post">` is for some reason, acting as `<form action="" method="get">` Does anyone know why this could be? I'm using Chrome on Windows 7.

EDIT: The whole form is this:

```
      <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="username" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username">
          <input type="password" class="input-block-level" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign in"><span>OR</span> <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST) === false) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
   $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password.';
} else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
   $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
} else if (user_active($username) === false) {
  $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account!';
} else if(strlen($password) > 32 ) {
     $errors[] = 'Password to long.';
}
  $login = login($username, $password);
  if($login === false){
    $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.';
  }else{
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
     header('Location: index.php');
     exit();

  }
}
if(empty($errors)===false){
?>
     <h1>We tried to log you in, but....</h1>
 <?php
      foreach($error as $errors){
        echo $error . '<br />';
     }
  } ?>
```

Comment: Post more code. Maybe you are using javascript to post the form and ignoring the method?

Comment: I added the whole form. No javascript is being used as far as I am aware.

Comment: Add the php code this should work its pretty trivial stuff really.

Comment: You've got a stray </button> tag in there. Did you mean to have value="Sign in" in the submit input tag?

Comment: By "acting as a get form" do you mean it's showing the query in the url on submit? Just testing as a file I'm not seeing this on Chrome/Win7. Full page source would probably help.

Comment: @AaronFowler yes I do. Added PHP code as well.